# Precisely defining the overlap depth, or deepest point of overlap, for ellipsoids and spheroids

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, algorithms, physics, surfaces

I was wondering if there is a robust mathematical definition for the 'deepest point of overlap' of ellipsoid (or, equally as good, spheroid) 1 that has overlapped with ellipsoid 2. For non-overlapping ellipsoids the point of nearest approach is defined as the points that share a common tangent plane normal to the vector joining the surfaces. This breaks down for overlapping surfaces.

I'm trying to develop some intuition and knowledge about the 'deepest points' such that I can eventually design a decent algorithm for finding these points. However, in the literature the phrase in quotation marks seems to be used quite loosely without being properly defined anywhere - at least that I have seen.

Many thanks if anyone has any insight...! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your overlap being convex (as intersection of two convex sets), a thorough mathematical definition is the *center of the maximal sphere included in the overlap*.

It is a particular case of what is called the "Utimate eroded set" in the context of the domain called **mathematical morphology**  ; see for example fig. 13.33 page 67 in [this document](https://user.engineering.uiowa.edu/%7Eaip/lectures/Slides-Milan-Chapter-13-part1.pdf) ; but in your case (where the overlap is convex), you aren't faced with such issues of local minima.

The next step is developing an algorithm for finding this point.

Comment: very interesting, I've never heard of this branch of mathematics haha. I will look into existing algorithms in this domain, thanks. The application is collisions between rigid body particles. The currently used approach is what's known as a geometric potential, not sure if you're familiar. :)

Comment: I have heard a little only about geometric potential.